# Sort Object inside two arrays by ascending/descending

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

So I need to add sort functionality to the fuel.name value inside this array...

```
const orders = [  
  {  
    "_id":"5d14a31490fb1e0012a3d2d8-1",
    "orderId":"0JL5ORM0JT-1",
    "created":"2019-06-27T11:05:56.377Z",
    "createdDate":"2019-06-27T09:05:56.377Z",
    "offers":[  
       {  
          "price":95.27,
          "fuel":{  
             "_id":"5ce13948eaef5200113b0de8",
             "name":"Diesel B7",
             "description":"Diesel",
             "lpt":0,
             "duty":0,
             "type":"SPOT",
             "created":"2019-05-19T11:08:56.417Z"
            }
         },
         {
           "price": 95.27,
           "fuel": {
             "_id": "5ce13948eaef5200113b0de8",
             "name": "Petrol",
             "description": "Petrol",
             "lpt": 0,
             "duty": 0,
             "type": "SPOT",
             "created": "2019-05-19T11:08:56.417Z"
           }
         },
         {
           "price": 95.27,
           "fuel": {
             "_id": "5ce13948eaef5200113b0de8",
             "name": "Fossil Fuel",
             "description": "Fossil Fuel",
             "lpt": 0,
             "duty": 0,
             "type": "SPOT",
             "created": "2019-05-19T11:08:56.417Z"
           },
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want the "offers" object to reorder based on the "fuel.name"

```
orders.sort((a: any, b: any) => a.offers[0].fuel.name.toUpperCase().localCompare(b.offers[0].fuel.name))
```

When I console log the above it just return the data in the same order. I have set up a fiddle below to replicate the issue I am having.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnxdrj0f/2/)

Comment: Please post a [MCVE], including a valid input structure in Javascript syntax (the code in the question is not valid Javascript syntax)

Comment: Is that any better @CertainPerformance ?

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: I have added a fiddle below @CertainPerformance

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Comment: You have a typo. It's `localeCompare` and not `localComapre`. The fiddle you have added is not reproducing the error you have posted. Also, do you want to sort the nested `offers` array or sort the `orders` array based on `offers[0].fuel.name`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance -  I have updated the question. Sorry I haven't posted on here in a while, I hope my updates help.

Comment: @adiga - Typo and fiddle updated

Comment: @adiga - I want to sort the offers array based on the fuel.name. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are currently sorting the `orders` array based on the first item inside `offers` array. Instead, you should `sort` each object's `offers` array inside the `orders`

```js
const orders=[{_id:"5d14a31490fb1e0012a3d2d8-1",orderId:"0JL5ORM0JT-1",created:"2019-06-27T11:05:56.377Z",createdDate:"2019-06-27T09:05:56.377Z",offers:[{price:95.27,fuel:{_id:"5ce13948eaef5200113b0de8",name:"Diesel B7",description:"Diesel",lpt:0,duty:0,type:"SPOT",created:"2019-05-19T11:08:56.417Z"}},{price:95.27,fuel:{_id:"5ce13948eaef5200113b0de8",name:"Petrol",description:"Petrol",lpt:0,duty:0,type:"SPOT",created:"2019-05-19T11:08:56.417Z"}},{price:95.27,fuel:{_id:"5ce13948eaef5200113b0de8",name:"Fossil Fuel",description:"Fossil Fuel",lpt:0,duty:0,type:"SPOT",created:"2019-05-19T11:08:56.417Z"},}]}];

orders.forEach(o => 
    o.offers.sort((a, b) => a.fuel.name.localeCompare(b.fuel.name))
);
    
console.log(orders)
```